# Android: Space between image and text

Tags: android, image, textview

This is my code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/error_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/error_image"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:textColor="#aa0000"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="16dp"/>
```

There is space between image and text and I want reduce this space, how can I do it?

Comment: Did you try changing the gravity to left?

Comment: @AbhishekShukla : when i set it to left, image is below the text.how can i fix it?

Comment: Set padding. It will do the trick

Comment: @ElhamGdz do you need `android:layout_width="match_parent"` compelsory.?

Comment: @SilentKiller :it does not work.

Comment: @SilentKiller: thanks but it doesn't need to set drawablePadding and without this work.anyway thank you very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you had set `android:layout_width="match_parent"`, `TextView` took all the width so the `drawablePadding` which you set will not work. So you need to set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`.

Try following code :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/error_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawablePadding="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#aa0000"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:text="adsfasdfa"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Answer (score 5):

You should set the property  **android:drawablePadding="0dp"**

Or in your java code, call `textView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(0)`;

Comment: you can not set int to `android:drawablePadding`

Comment: @Robin `sp` is used for text better to keep `dp` for margin and padding. :)